# Automatically Login is not Authenticated

Tags: html, authentication, web

I have a web app that i use for industrial purpose. It is a ready-made commercial app. When the web server runs in my own computer, i can successfully login to web app automatically with the html code below:

```
<html>

<title>Login Page</title>

<body>

<form id="loginForm" method="post" name='login' action="http://localhost/_common/lvl5/main.jsp?wbs=527&operatorlocale=en" onsubmit="document.getElementById('pass').value = CJMaker.makeString(document.getElementById('pass').value);" >

<input id="nameInput" type="text" value="Administrator" name="name" size="25" maxlength="80" tabindex="1" style="width:175px;">

<input type="password" value="mhoto0606" id="pass" name="pass"  autocomplete="off" size="25" maxlength="80" tabindex="1" style="width:175px;  ">

</form> 

<script>
document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But when i try to connect to web app remotely, it gives me error such that "login is not authenticated". For this, i use the code below. Only difference is the adress specified in "action" attribute. This time i use the ip adress of server instead of "localhost"

```
<html>

<title>Login Page</title>

<body>

<form id="loginForm" method="post" name='login' action="http://###.##.##.##/_common/lvl5/main.jsp?wbs=527&operatorlocale=en" onsubmit="document.getElementById('pass').value = CJMaker.makeString(document.getElementById('pass').value);" >

<input id="nameInput" type="text" value="Administrator" name="name" size="25" maxlength="80" tabindex="1" style="width:175px;">

<input type="password" value="mhoto0606" id="pass" name="pass"  autocomplete="off" size="25" maxlength="80" tabindex="1" style="width:175px;  ">

</form> 

<script>
document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This web app only works with Internet Explorer.

I could not come up with a solution. I am eagerly waiting for your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really storing credentials in HTML? You are a doing one big mistake with security. You should not do this. I hope you know what you are doing!

Comment: Yes, i know what i am doing. It is not critical. Because that html will only be stored in my comp. And i planning of using some programming skills to make it more secure!